# Stop Safari on iOS7 prompting to save card data

Tags: html, safari, ios7

I have a client's site which is prompting them to save card details under iOS7. I can find absolutely nothing regarding how or what is causing iOS to decide this is the right thing to do - does anyone have any ideas?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were running into this exact issue. As Guy Thomas mentioned, it was due to having password fields in the form with the CC fields.

After lots of testing, I determined that the password fields could be switched to a different `type` before submitting the form (in our case, just switched to `hidden`). This allowed the form to submit even after choosing "Not Now" in the dialog.

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
    try{
        $("input[type=password]").attr("type", "hidden");
    } catch(ex){
        try {
            $("input[type=password]").prop("type", "hidden");
        } catch(ex) {}
    }          
});
```

I added the try/catches because depending on browser/jquery version, changing the type attribute would error.

Comment: Just a comment that I am using this code in our WordPress plugin Paid Memberships Pro. I just noticed that the latest versions of Safari for Mac (maybe tied to the Mac OSX version) are also doing this. I thought it was only happening on iPhones and iPads.


I have a user agent match around the code so the password fields don't disappear on other browsers (kind of alarming to users).


     if(userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || userAgent.match(/Safari/i)) { ... }

Comment: @LuckySpoon - I know this is an old thread but you should accept ry4nolson answer as it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

After performing quite a bit of testing on this I determined that there is some kind of analysis being done on the data actually input by the user. I removed all references to credit card, number, cvv, etc. and was still receiving the icloud keychain popup when I entered a "real" card number.. As soon as I started putting in "1234567890123456" and the like, the pop up would not display.

More problematic was when a user would click "not now" the form would not submit without a complete page refresh. I tracked this down to the form having an input of type="password".. As soon as I changed the type to "text", the form would properly submit after the user clicked "not now".

Answer (score 0):

Add `autocomplete="off"` to both your input and form and it will stop saving the data you entered.

Comment: If you are sure you put that in BOTH your input and form tag, and this only affects iOS7 users, then it's the iCloud keychain feature you'll have to disable on the deviec. To disable these options, just go to Settings -> Safari and disable —Use Contact Info, Names and Passwords, and Credit Cards.

Comment: Never heard of autocomplete on a form tag - will give that a go.

Comment: In addition, if a Web author does not want users to see the AutoComplete feature for any field in a form, the AUTOCOMPLETE attribute can be used to disable the feature for the entire form.
See here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533032(v=vs.85).ASPX

Comment: some people would say autocomplete=”off” is not valid markup with XHTML Transitional, which is a common DOCTYPE. You can use this to keep a vaild markup 
if (document.getElementsByTagName) {

var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName(“input”);

for (i=0; inputElements[i]; i++) {

if (inputElements[i].className && (inputElements[i].className.indexOf(“disableAutoComplete”) != -1)) {

inputElements[i].setAttribute(“autocomplete”,”off”);

}

}

}

Comment: Interesting - I'm not too bothered with being "valid" markup (like anything really is anway) - I've set autocomplete on the form, will report back. Thanks all :)

Comment: Update - still prompting to save with autocomplete set to off.

Comment: @LuckySpoon did you find a way to disable this without renaming all the fields? As autocomplete="off" won't disable this and this popup breaks all other javascript execution etc

Comment: @AntonS Sorry no, didn't make any ground on this at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Safari needs some type of clue that you're submitting credit card info. If you control the name of the form elements, then name the elements to something unrelated to a credit card:

This prompts autofill:

```
<form action="test" method="post" id="credit">
    Name:<input type="text" name="cardholder"  />
    <br/>
    Credit Card Type:
    <select name="cardtype"  >
        <option></option>
        <option value="amex">amex</option>
        <option value="visa">visa</option>
        <option value="mastercard">mastercard</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    Credit Card:<input type="text" name="cardnumber" />
    <br/>
    Expiration:<input type="text" name="expirationdate" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This does not prompt:

```
<form action="test" method="post" id="credit" autocomplete="off" >
    Name:<input type="text" name="h" autocomplete="off"  />
    <br/>
    Credit Card Type:
    <select name="t" autocomplete="off"  >
        <option></option>
        <option value="amex">amex</option>
        <option value="visa">visa</option>
        <option value="mastercard">mastercard</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    Credit Card:<input type="text" name="n" autocomplete="off" />
    <br/>
    Expiration:<input type="text" name="d" autocomplete="off"  />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```