# iOS Native credit card autofill function conflicts with mobile checkout

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, checkout, credit-card

In Mobile Safari IOS 8,when I have Auto Fill enabled for Credit Card, in checkout, when I try to add a new card, safari prompts to save the card or not, and if I click on any of the options Safari Crashes. 
As per my research, please find below few links to discussion on same topic on apple forums:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6652733

https://discussions.apple.com/message/23512169

Has any one any solution for this???

Answer (score 1):

@gupta120 : There is a different Thread  that actually  points to the case where if we have a  input type = password in the same form that has the credit card form, the Credt Card auto  save native functionality becomes un responsive and crashes safary,
Pleas echeck the link 
[Stop Safari on iOS7 prompting to save card data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210093/stop-safari-on-ios7-prompting-to-save-card-data)
Essentially we need  to intercept the form submit  and change the input  password type to any thing other than  password

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
    try{
        $("input[type=password]").attr("type", "hidden");
    } catch(ex){
        try {
            $("input[type=password]").prop("type", "hidden");
        } catch(ex) {}
    }          
});
```